# How to enter accented vowels in KDE

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, kde, locale

I am going to use a PC with US keyboard and KDE (Kubuntu).
While the US keyboard is perfect for programming, it isn't to enter Italian words with accented vowels (both lower and upper case).

I'd like to know if there's a way to enter the accented vowels (àèéìòù and the likes). Both using the "charmap" tool and switching the keyboard layout is not an option as it would be needed very often.

I have already read the answers to another [similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80454/is-there-a-quick-way-to-enter-uppercase-accented-characters) (involving GNOME) but it seems it's not working.

For example, if I press Alt-Gr+Shift+"A", and then "``" (*only one inverted quote, this editor gets weird when it sees a single invrted quote!*) I get "Æ`" with either left or right shift instead of "à".

Any hint?

Comment: You may want to switch to the keyboard layout _English (US, international with dead keys)_.

Comment: I know this option, but it's quite annoying to continuously switch between keyboard layouts while typing. I will modify the question to be more clear. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Another option is a compose key; maybe you gave up too soon. If you enable the XIM option in _Input Method Configuration_, you should get access to a huge number of combinations in the file `/usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose`.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson , please elaborate more on "enable the XIM option in Input Method Configuration". Thanks!

Comment: Oh.. It's a tool for configuring input methods. It can be started from a terminal window with the command `im-config` (or from the GUI if you search for _Input Method Configuration_).

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I think I enabled xim with `im-config -n xim`. According to the file `/usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose`, I should be able to input an "à" with a "<dead_grave> <a>" keystroke. But I have no idea what does it mean!

Comment: I posted an answer.

Answer (score 5):

For the case you use the basic English (US) keyboard layout, there are no dead keys, and hence the `<dead_grave> <a>` method does not apply.

Instead you need to define a key as the compose key, which lets you use the next method - `<Multi_key> <grave> <a>` - to type à:

<kbd>Compose</kbd> followed by <kbd>`</kbd> followed by <kbd>A</kbd>

On KDE you define a compose key via Settings/Hardware/Keyboard/Advanced, Position Compose key (credit to [Larry H. Poort](https://askubuntu.com/users/880203/larry-h-poort))